# LaTeX minted Error

Tags: errors, texmaker, minted

I receive the following errors:

```
! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this packag
```

in TexMaker Settings i wrote:

> LaTeX : "/usr/texbin/latex" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex -shell-escape
>
> PdfLaTex: "/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode
>   %.tex -shell-escape

But the error still doesn't vanish ...

Comment: Move `%1.tex` to the end. Also, did you install pygmentize?

Comment: @Sigur Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT., done!

Answer (score 7):

The error says `! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.`

So you have to use the flag `-shell-escape` when compiling, that is, use it before the name of the file.

To do this, move `%.tex` to the end.

```
-interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

I will post this for future users facing a similiar issue.

**Check your antivirus program.** In my case "Norton" blocked the process "pygmentize.exe".

I got followed error:

```
Package minted Error: Cannot find Pygments style default. \end{minted}
```